# High CPU usage occurs periodically on the subscriber

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge-replication

I have set up a merge publication and a subscriber with push subscription mode.

On the subscriber, I notice the CPU usage is going high periodically.

[image]

It may take about 40 seconds for the CPU Usage come back to 0%. And it occurs at same time as long as the Synchronization Status display : *"Uploading data changes to the Publisher"*. This only occurs at subscriber, the publisher is normally.

I've go to  `Reports > Top Queries by Total CPU time` at the subscriber to see which queries make the CPU usage go high and below is the result:

[image]

I don't know what to do next to fix this issue. Does anybody have an idea on how to solve it?

Comment: Hmm, there was a problem with this in SQL 2005 but I can't seem to find a similar fix for 2008, Just posting here in case somebody finds this question through search: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942668